# How can Offline install gradle in my Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How can **Offline install** *gradle* in my *Android Studio*??

Android Studio 0.8.6

gradle: http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip

My laptop does not have internet.

i install Android Studio 0.8.6(32bit) and JDK(32Bit).
Android Studio 0.8.6 is work But need to gradle-1.12 for Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste it in the C:\Users\username.gradle directory.